# lvalue refference vs rvale refference - примеры на c11++

Tags: c++11, function-overloading

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f(const int& x)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue reference to const overload f(" << x << ")\n";
}

void f(int&& x)
{
    std::cout << "rvalue reference overload f(" << x << ")\n";
}

#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    f(3);
    int&& z = 3;
    f(z);

}
```

Почему в данном случае при вызове f(z), вызывается const lvalue функция, а не вторая, ведь тип z является rvalue refference ?

и второй вопрос:

```
class A {
  public:
    A() { std::cout << "A constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "A destructor" << std::endl; }

    A(const A& other) {
        std::cout << "A copy constructor" << std::endl; }
    A(A&& other) {
        std::cout << "A move constructor" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    B() : A() { std::cout << "B constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "B destructor" << std::endl; }

    B(const B& other) : A(other) {
        std::cout << "B copy constructor" << std::endl; }
    B(B&& other) : A(other) {
        std::cout << "B move constructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<B> v;
    std::cout << ">>> Pushing first element" << std::endl;
    v.push_back(B());
    std::cout << ">>> First element was pushed" << std::endl;
}
```

Почему в  данном случае вызывается A copy constructor, а не A move constructor:
как это связанно с lvalue и rvalue, и с overloading ?

**update:**

изменил строчку как и было сказано в отличном ответе:

```
B(B&& other) : A(std::move<B&>(other)) {
```

Благодарю чему вывод теперь выглядит так:

```
>>> Pushing first element
A constructor
B constructor
A move constructor
B move constructor
B destructor
A destructor
>>> First element was pushed
>>> Pushing second element
A constructor
B constructor
A move constructor
B move constructor
A copy constructor
B copy constructor
B destructor
A destructor
B destructor
A destructor
>>> Second element was pushed
B destructor
A destructor
B destructor
A destructor
```

**Обновленный вопрос:**

**Последние два copy ctor'a вызываются насколько я понимаю при увеличение величины вектора и при их копирование (насколько я понимаю, реализация через динамический массив), если не в этом причина, поправьте. Как сделать так, чтобы и тех местах вызывался move ctor ?**

попробовал так:

```
v.push_back(std::move<B&&>)B()();
```

Ничего не изменило.
Когда эти элементы уже находятся в векторе, насколько я понимаю, они уже являются lvalue.

Странность в том, что в задание (исследование поведение rvalue и lvalue) сказано, что можно дополнительно изменить как-то ту же строчку о которой была речь выше каким-то специальным specifier'ом, который ради таких случаев добавлен в c++11, чтобы вызывать именно move constructor и в этом случае. 
Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Если у вас появился новый вопрос, то и задавайте его новым вопросом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Именованные `rvalue-ссылки` рассматриваются как `lvalue`.

В этом объявлении

```
int&& z = 3;
```

переменная `z` имеет тип `rvalue-ссылки`, которая привязана к временному выражению, состоящего из целочисленного литерала, равного 3. Тем не менее, переменная `z` - это `lvalue`.

Например, вы можете применить оператор получения адреса

```
std::cout << ( void * )&z << std::endl;
```

Об этом, например, явно сказано в параграфе №7 раздела 5 Expressions  стандарта C++

> In general, the eﬀect of this rule is that **named rvalue references are
>   treated as lvalues** and unnamed rvalue references to objects are
>   treated as xvalues; rvalue references to functions are treated as
>   lvalues whether named or not.

Поэтому когда вызывается функция `f`, то компилятор ищет перегруженную функцию, которая принимает в качестве аргумента `lvalue`. В результате будет выбрана функция, объявленная как

```
void f(const int& x)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue reference to const overload f(" << x << ")\n";
}
```

Вы можете превратить `z` в `rvalue` , используя приведение типв `static_cast`, или стандартную функцию `std::move`, или просто  для арифметического типа, например, поставив унарный знак плюса.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает описанные подходы по превращению `lvalue` в `rvalue`, и что переменная `z`, хотя она имеет тип `rvalue-ссылки`, тем не менее является `lvalue`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void f(int&& x)
{
    std::cout << "rvalue reference overload f(" << x << ")\n";
}

void f(const int& x)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue reference to const overload f(" << x << ")\n";
}

int main() 
{
    f( 3 );

    int &&z = 3;

    f( z );

    f( static_cast<int &&>( z ) );

    f( std::move( z ) );

    f( +z );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
rvalue reference overload f(3)
lvalue reference to const overload f(3)
rvalue reference overload f(3)
rvalue reference overload f(3)
rvalue reference overload f(3)
```

Аналогичная ситуация имеет место и с параметром конструктора. Хотя он имеет тип `rvalue-ссылки`, тем не менее сам параметр является `lvalue`. Поэтому когда он передается базовому классу в качестве аргумента, то будет вызываться конструктор базового класса, который принимает `lvalue`.

Если хотите поподробнее познакомиться с этим материалом, то советую почитать статью **Скотта Майерса** в журнале ACCU Overload №111 за октябрь 2012 года [Universal References in C++11](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload111.pdf).

Это международный журнал профессиональных программистов.

Кстати сказать, заодно в этом же журнале ACCU Overload #126 за апрель 2015 года можете почитать мою статью [iterator_pair - a simple and useful iterator adapter.](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload126.pdf):)

Относительно **ACCU**, то это

> The ACCU is an organisation of programmers who care about
>   professionalism in programming. That is, we care about writing good
>   code, and about writing it in a good way. We are dedicated to raising
>   the standard of programming. The articles in this magazine have all
>   been written by ACCU members - by programmers, for programmers - and
>   have been contributed free of charge

Что касается вашего дополнительного вопроса, то просто зарезервируйте достаточно место в векторе, как , например,

```
v.reserve( 2 );
```

Тогда не будет перераспределения памяти, и, соответственно, копирования объектов вектора на новый участок памяти.

Либо у конструктора перемещения укажите спецификатор `noexcept`. Тогда вместо конструктора копирования будет вызываться конструктор перемещения.

Вот простой пример

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct B
{
    B() { std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }

    B( const B & ) { std::cout << "B( const B & )" << std::endl; }

    B( B && ) noexcept { std::cout << "B( B && )" << std::endl; }
    //        ^^^^^^^
    ~B() { std::cout << "~B()" << std::endl; }
};  

int main() 
{
    std::vector<B> v;

    std::cout << "adding first element" << std::endl;
    v.push_back( B() );

    std::cout << "\nadding second element" << std::endl;
    v.emplace_back( B() );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: О последнем вашем примере - вы, наверное, имели в виду `noexcept`?

Comment: @Harry Да, я имел в виду noexcept.:)

Answer (score 1):

В силу моего разумения - в стандартах я не до такой степени силен, чтоб навскидку цитировать.

В первой части - объявляйте `z` как угодно, но раз есть имя - есть адрес, а значит, это будет попросту `int`.

Во второй - после того как rvalue-ссылка передана как параметр, она получает имя, а значит, теперь это lvalue. Хотите перемещающий конструктор - делайте так:

```
B(B&& other) : A(std::move(other)) {
```

Тот же способ можно применить и к `f(z)`: `f(std::move(z))`.

Конкретные ссылки на стандарт, думаю, даст [@Vlad from Moscow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183394/vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: Да, это был верный ответ, проблема осталась с нижними двумя вызовами, насколькоя  понимаю при увеличение вектора. Не подскажешь ? Подробно описал в обновленном вопросе выше.

Comment: Как я и рассчитывал, вам основательно ответил @VladfromMoscow - только с одной поправкой, волшебный спецификатор - не `nothrow`, а `noexcept`. Кстати, должен заметить, что стандарт - стандартом, но, например, тот же Visual C++ просто игнорирует спецификаторы и всегда вызывает только перемещающий конструктор :(